# Typescript: Type checking correct way

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

In typescript to use features like type checking and strong typing, many a time people uses class and many a times interface, like:

Class Person

```
class Person{
name: string;
age: number;
}

let users:Person[] = [
    { name: 'david', age: 25 },
    { name: 'paul', age: 54 }
];
```

Interface Person:

```
Class Person

interface Person{
name: string;
age: number;
}

let users:Person[] = [
    { name: 'david', age: 25 },
    { name: 'paul', age: 54 }
];
```

Also, we use these as generics with Observables as `Observale<Person>`

So my question here is to know which is the correct way to type checking and strong typing

1. Using class
2. Using interface

Because people are not very much clear about this in typescript and they use interchangeably the terms class and interface. In many blogs, tutorials, projects especially Angular projects I have seen people confused.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? When you say *"people"*, who do you mean? In this simple case, it doesn't really matter whether you use the class or the interface (although the latter is more idiomatic), the result is the same. I'd recommend reading e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html, which definitely doesn't confuse them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe By people I mean, I have seen many a time people use the class as a model in Angular, and many times interface to create their model. And model here is just for type checking especially while creating arrays or making HTTP get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your case of classes, it is not well implemented.

You are using them as interfaces object. What I mean is that in your sample:

```
let users:Person[] = [
    { name: 'david', age: 25 },
    { name: 'paul', age: 54 }
];
```

These are objects, and not instances of the class `Person`.

This is the correct usage in case of interfaces, but in case of classes you should do something like:

```
const p1 = new Person();
p1.name = 'david';
p1.age = 25;
const p2 = new Person();
p2.name = 'paul';
p2.age = 54;
let users:Person[] = [p1, p2];
```

In this way you are actually creating an array of `Person` instances.

About what to use, that really depends on the case.

Interfaces are straight forward objects which reflect the properties you define.

Classes are something more. 
Let's suppose that for each person you want a method which returns you the name and the age.

With the interface you cannot do that.

With the class you can define a method once in the class, and then call it on all the instances, like for example:

```
class Person{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  getInfo(): string {
    return `I am ${this.name} of age ${this.age}`;
  }
}
```

And then you can call it over all the instances, like for example:

`console.log(p1.getInfo();)`

In cases that you do want to use them just as type checking for the object properties, for example returned by an HTTP request, go for `Interface`.

If you need extra operations over these models, go for `Class` instead.